# Simple text editor with contenteditable weird behavior in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text-editor, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to make something like this simple text editor:
[contenteditable text editor](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/contenteditable.htm).
I'm using AngularJS v1.1.4 it works fine on firefox lates but on chrome latest the buttons does not work. here's a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ifVF9K2dKmw7EJW1IwA8?p=preview).

## Update:

The problem is more complex then I thought.

#### Firefox:

The example of the text editor with the contenteditable div works in a way:
When I click on the bold button with text selected the text become bold but the cursor or caret (that thing that move when you type with the keyboard) is not always visible.
But when using the iframe method the iframe is unclickable.

#### Chrome:

The example of the text editor with the contenteditable div works in a way:
When I click on the bold button with text selected nothing happen, but when I invoke the command through the console it work (weird).
Iframe methode works fine here.

#### To see examples:

- [Editor with contenteditable](http://plnkr.co/edit/ifVF9K2dKmw7EJW1IwA8?p=preview)
- [Editor with iframe](http://plnkr.co/edit/wIXEd3voLh6ScImo06x3?p=preview)

Any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not work on Firefox. I cannot apply any style.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 20 and it work fine for me but in Chrome 26 it doesn't, does the first example work for you?

Comment: Just updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make to work in Chrome, you have to use `ng-mousedown` instead of `ng-click`.

It doesn't work with `ng-click` in non frame mode for a very simple reason. When you click on the button to format text, focus is lost from editable area, and when command is executed no text is selected. But mousedown event happens before focus is lost therefore you loose focus and selection from editor in the end, but command execution occurs before focus lost.